# custom opencv.js + wasm: Using cv.matFromArray() results in cv.Mat() is not a constructor. How to load the `module` correct in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, opencv, webassembly, emscripten

I followed this tutorial to create a custom opencv.js [1]: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html

But I'm stuck with the correct laoding in my Typescript project. The created script mainly consists of this glue code:

```js
(function (root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(function () {
      return (root.cv = factory());
    });
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    // Node. Does not work with strict CommonJS, but
    // only CommonJS-like environments that support module.exports,
    // like Node.
    module.exports = factory();
  } else if (typeof window === 'object') {
    // Browser globals
    root.cv = factory();
  } else if (typeof importScripts === 'function') {
    // Web worker
    root.cv = factory();
  } else {
    // Other shells, e.g. d8
    root.cv = factory();
  }
}(this, function () {
  
var cv = (() => {
  var _scriptDir = typeof document !== 'undefined' && document.currentScript ? document.currentScript.src : undefined;
  if (typeof __filename !== 'undefined') _scriptDir = _scriptDir || __filename;
  return (
function(moduleArg = {}) {

var Module=moduleArg;
...
Module["TermCriteria"]= TermCriteria;
Module["matFromArray"]= function(rows,cols,type,array){
var mat=new cv.Mat(rows,cols,type);
switch(type){
...
return mat};
...

  return moduleArg.ready
}
);
})();
;
if (typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
  module.exports = cv;
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd'])
  define([], () => cv);

  if (typeof Module === 'undefined')
    Module = {};
  return cv(Module);
}));
```

I load the code like this:

```js
const opencvModule = await import('./custom_opencv.js');
      cv = opencvModule;
```

Since I use await, I can make sure that the wasm code is fully loaded and ready to be used.
If my following code uses `new cv.Mat()` I receive a result. However if I use: `cv.matFromArray()` I will always receive `cv.Mat() is not a constructor`.

So my workaround is to give `cv` another scope (?) in the custom_opencv.js. Since we have:

```js
Module["matFromArray"]= function(rows,cols,type,array){
var mat=new cv.Mat(rows,cols,type);
switch(type){
...
return mat};
```

I added: `let (var) cv=Module` after this line:

```js
function(moduleArg = {}) {

var Module=moduleArg;
var cv=Module;
```

So now it works, but I must do something wrong, since I expect the code to work without this modification? If you need any further information, please let me know and I will edit the article. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I used a similar custom build. CV runs the WASM module in its scope. You invoke the module (with any config for pre/post)... then it should be GC. But you may assign the cv variable WITHIN the module for reused code. Still the module re-inits and is destroyed, from what I read and tested. It makes sense to load the script and test for window.cv before processing a module. Depending much on your custom build flags...